# Should all options appear on a view screen?

Tags: forms, user-expectation, edit

I'm designing screens for a business web app. I have view and edit modes for records, with each mode having its own screen. Should I display all options on the view screens, but with the widgets disabled? I was thinking of displaying only the entered data, but I'm not sure if it's better for users to see what they entered against other available options.

I'm especially thinking of checkbox groups. However, for listboxes this probably won't be practical.

Comment: Hi Jason, it will probably depend a lot on your users and what they would prefer. Personally, if there is an easy way to get into the edit mode and see other options I wouldn't mind if the view page only lists my current settings.

Comment: Hi Jason, it would be greatly helpful if it would be possible for you to share a screenshot of the scenario. It's understandable if you can't do the same due to non-disclosure issues though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I'll show only the selected options for now. I might add a user preference later for users to select if they want to see all options on view screens.